# Python while loop - want to repeat or exit game with Y/N option

Tags: python, while-loop

I made a simple Battleship game. At the end of the game, whether it ends in victory of defeat, I want the user to be able to play again or quit. This code intends to take an input, make sure it's either "y" or "n" and then set a variable controling the initial while loop to false if the input is "n". Somehow, as loop runs again, no matter what I do, the input it set back to "y" - I've checked using print statements and it definitely gets correctly set to "n" but if I print the value again immediately after the while loop somehow it is "y." The while loop runs again regardless of input. How can I fix it so "n" correctly exits the loop?

```
restart = "y"
while restart[0] not in ("n", "N"):
    def play_again():
       print ("")
       restart = input("Enter y to play again or n to quit: ")
       print ("")
       try: 
            x = str(restart)
       except ValueError:
            print ("Please enter y or n.")
            print ("")
            play_again()
       else:
            if str(restart) != "y" and str(restart) != "n":
                print ("Please enter y or n.")
                print ("")
                play_again()
    *game*
    play_again()
```

Comment: The `restart` inside `play_again` is *completely unrelated* to the one controlling the `while` loop; it only exists inside that function. You should `return` and assign the new value.

Answer (score -1):

```
def restart_game():
    try:
        restart = input("Enter y to play again or n to quit: ")
        if restart == "y":
            return True
        if restart == "n":
            return False
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter y or n.")
        return True


while True:
    print 'Playing the game ...'
    if not restart_game(): break
```

Comment: True, but completely irrelevant.

Comment: Deleted the old stuff. Hopefully, this code will help you.